# Error converting YAML to JSON: did not find expected key

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I just created a new Helm chart but when I run `helm install --dry-run --debug` I get:

Error: YAML parse error on multi-camera-tracking/templates/multi-camera-tracking.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 30: did not find expected key

And this is my Yaml file:

```
---
# apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: multi-camera-tracking
  annotations:
    Process: multi-camera-tracking
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: multi-camera-tracking
spec:
  serviceName: multi-camera-tracking
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: multi-camera-tracking
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: multi-camera-tracking
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: multi-camera-tracking
        env:
        - name: MCT_PUB_PORT
          value: {{ .Values.MCT_PUB_PORT | quote }}
        - name: SCT_IP_ADDR_CSV
          value: {{ .Values.SCT_IP_ADDR_CSV | quote }}
        - name: SCT_PUB_PORT_CSV
          value: {{ .Values.SCT_PUB_PORT1 | quote }}, {{ .Values.SCT_PUB_PORT2 | quote }}
        image: {{ .Values.image_multi_camera_tracking }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.MCT_PUB_PORT }}
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.1
            memory: 250Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 4
            memory: 10Gi
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - ls
            - /tmp
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 60
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    Process: multi-camera-tracking
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: multi-camera-tracking
  name: multi-camera-tracking
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "MCT_PUB_PORT"
    port: {{ .Values.MCT_PUB_PORT }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.MCT_PUB_PORT }}
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: multi-camera-tracking
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The strange thing is I have created multiple other helm charted and they all are very similar to this but this one doesn't work and produces error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the reason why it is not working. First of all, it is allowed to have comma-separated values but the problematic part was the quotations.

This is the wrong syntax:

```
value: {{ .Values.SCT_PUB_PORT1 | quote }}, {{ .Values.SCT_PUB_PORT2 | quote }}
```

And this is the correct one:

```
value: {{ .Values.SCT_PUB_PORT1 }}, {{ .Values.SCT_PUB_PORT2 }}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the `template` command with `--debug` is the expected debug route for this kind of issue, e.g:

```
helm template  ./yourchart/ -f your-overrides.yaml -n your-ns --debug
```

Here helm will do its best to try and produce the YAML, and allow you to inspect and see whether you can see errors more clearly.

Comment: And most importantly, throw a big old ugly error where it fails to render something, giving you a better idea of where to look.  If you have conditionals that chop whole blocks of yaml out, you could be looking at line 500 of the template file that is rendering line 359 of the real yaml.  `helm template` shows you more clearly where to look.

Comment: Debug adds no usable information. These errors are like looking for a needle in a haystack except you don't even know if it's a needle or if it's in the haystack.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Tried `install --debug` as well as `lint` but was wishing if something could print the generated yaml so that I can visualise the error.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had written

```
name: { { template "cp-kafka.fullname" . } }-jaas-configmap
```

due to that giving error.

Right would be

```
name: {{ template "cp-kafka.fullname" . }}-jaas-configmap
```

The difference is space between curly brackets.

Answer (score 4):

i had the similar issue, after all the debugging i found out that the issue was with the identation of one of the file, i was referring to in the configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-conf
  labels:
    {{- include "mytemp.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
{{ (tpl (.Files.Glob "configs/MyJobConf.conf").AsConfig . ) | nindent 4 }}
```

**Identation issue was not in the configmap.yaml but MyJobConf.conf** (helm is parsing it as yaml)

After correcting it, it solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

One way to debug this problem is to do a dry-run and render the template to see what is causing the issue on the offending line.

`helm install [Chart] [flags] --dry-run --debug`

This would allow you to see which keys are not indented well as this issue is sometimes caused by the wrong indentation.

Comment: This obviously doesn't allow to see anything but Go stack trace.

Comment: It renders the YAML output as well and if wrongly indented, you can see where the error is in the indention or if a field is wrongly formatted.

Comment: No, it obviously doesn't if error occurs before Helm is able to render valid YAML, which is obviously the case for wrong template syntax. Actually I can't imagine situation when Helm shows rendered YAML and stack trace simultaneously in dry-run mode.

Comment: Same case as @miz

Comment: Dry run fails on a parsing error, so the actual rendered manifest is never shown. Helm doesn't show the preprocessed YAML (values applied), so you have to infer that by resolving the template in your head and hoping it matches reality... Helm should ideally show the preprocessed manifest and spare the world much pain...

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar error with rendering an xml.
in `values.yaml` I had:

```
xml: >
  <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://www.sso.com/diohadohad">
  <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
  <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:X509Data>
  <ds:X509Certificate>JJDHDHASDAIDSFHDSGERGSERGISJDFGSERIGSERGRSG TEImxWRRX87Xj1MZyxjiBQ+ilySMD9OsskTSwVysTwWK+eFM40gVXFWBeAuoQvkb2rvZ2+8rJySQ rYC+dMIfKE6EEwnD6+XzwcKpTjs7TChviMZ6LxNbMJO6ybJPxoJt0zV0Aago9UEAF2U3NVuRTmsE TUOk9mbI14ULcZM03ltjSZqi</ds:X509Certificate>
  </ds:X509Data>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://mycompany.sso.com/app/asdfasdf/sso/saml"/>
  <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://mycompany.sso.com/app/asdfasdfsdf/sso/saml"/>
  </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
  </md:EntityDescriptor>
```

And for some reason I couldn't render this value. I was looking for character that was causing me trouble, and found out it was the double-quote `"` char.
Since it's an xml, the quick fix for me was to change this character to a single-quote `'` instead:

```
xml: >
  <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata' entityID='http://www.sso.com/diohadohad'>
  <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned='false' protocolSupportEnumeration='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'>
  <md:KeyDescriptor use='signing'>
  <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'>
  <ds:X509Data>
  <ds:X509Certificate>JJDHDHASDAIDSFHDSGERGSERGISJDFGSERIGSERGRSG TEImxWRRX87Xj1MZyxjiBQ+ilySMD9OsskTSwVysTwWK+eFM40gVXFWBeAuoQvkb2rvZ2+8rJySQ rYC+dMIfKE6EEwnD6+XzwcKpTjs7TChviMZ6LxNbMJO6ybJPxoJt0zV0Aago9UEAF2U3NVuRTmsE TUOk9mbI14ULcZM03ltjSZqi</ds:X509Certificate>
  </ds:X509Data>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:SingleSignOnService Binding='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST' Location='https://mycompany.sso.com/app/asdfasdf/sso/saml'/>
  <md:SingleSignOnService Binding='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect' Location='https://mycompany.sso.com/app/asdfasdfsdf/sso/saml'/>
  </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
  </md:EntityDescriptor>
```